# Azure time trigger function not firing on hourly basis

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have developed an time trigger azure function which is set to fired every hour but it is not triggering the function as expected. It's triggering behavior is very strange. I am attaching it's executing logs.

[image]

The cron expression for triggering the function is as follows:

> 0 0 * * * *

Anyone has any idea whats wrong with this?

Comment: Can you try with the following expression `0 0 * ? * * *`?

Comment: It says invalid cron expression.

Answer (score 4):

The expression for hourly schedule is:

```
0 0 */1 * * *
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function#update-the-timer-schedule

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below cron job expression,
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#crongenerator
 0 0 * ? * * *

But according to MS documents what you have used is correct. Are you using application insights ? 
https://codehollow.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer